# Why my stored procedure works different to the MySQL console?

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysql-connector

I am programming this stored procedure:

Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` 
PROCEDURE `IncrementarPresupuesto`() NO SQL 
UPDATE `concepto` SET `Mdisponible`=`Mdisponible`+`Mquincenal` WHERE 1$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Console

```
UPDATE `concepto` SET `
     Mdisponible`=`Mdisponible`+`Mquincenal` WHERE 1
```

When I run the same query in the console, it works, but when I run the stored procedure with the same query it does not work.

`Mdisponible` & `Mquincenal` are columns with double datatype and I want to add in `Mdisponible`the total of `Mdisponible`+`Mquincenal`

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I am not getting any error, but there are not changes when I run the stored procedure.

Comment: What client is running it?  I ask because it may not be showing the errors.